# Zip File with Python Shutil like File Explorer

Tags: python, zip, directory, shutil

### Background

I am trying to zip a directory with python shutil like this:

```
shutil.make_archive("~/Desktop/zipfile", 'zip', "~/Documents/foldertozip")
```

but the result only zips the files *inside* "foldertozip". So for instance,

```
foldertozip
    -- file1
    -- file2
zipfile.zip
    -- file1
    -- file2
```

On the other hand, if I zip it from windows file explorer or mac finder, I get the following:

```
foldertozip
    -- file1
    -- file2
zipfile.zip
    -- foldertozip
        -- file1
        -- file2
```

### Question

How can I use shutil to do the same thing that I could do from a file explorer and include the base directory? I know I could copy "foldertozip" to a folder with the same name and then zip that folder, but I would prefer a cleaner solution if at all possible.

Comment: Double check documentation on how to provide the arguments, e.g. absolute path, trailing slash..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`make_archive` will do what you want if you pass both `root_dir` and `base_dir`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive).

```
import shutil

shutil.make_archive('~/Desktop/zipfile', 'zip', '~/Documents/', 'foldertozip')
```

Comment: Let me get this straight...root_dir does not include the folder to compress, and base_dir is the folder to compress? Why is it base_dir instead of base_file if that is the case? Furthermore, why do both default to the current directory?

Comment: As the docs state, `root_dir` is the root of the archive -- this is the directory into which you'd `cd` before running `zip`. `base_dir` is optional and becomes the `common prefix` in the zip file. I looked into [make_archive](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py#l512)'s source to figure out your default question: `base_dir`, if not provided, defaults to `os.curdir` which is a constant; its value is "." This is different than the current working directory (`os.getcwd()`). `os.curdir` in this case simply means "no base" or "no prefix"..!

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of make_archive:

```
shutil.make_archive(base_name, format[, root_dir[, base_dir[, verbose[, dry_run[, owner[, group[, logger]]]]]]])
```

Create an archive file (eg. zip or tar) and returns its name.

**base_name** is the name of the file to create, including the path, minus any format-specific extension. format is the archive format: one of “zip”, “tar”, “bztar” or “gztar”.

**root_dir** is a directory that will be the root directory of the archive; ie. we typically chdir into root_dir before creating the archive.

**base_dir** is the directory where we start archiving from; ie. base_dir will be the common prefix of all files and directories in the archive.

If I understand the question correctly, you need to have base_dir equal to "foldertozip" and root_dir equal to the parent directory of "foldertozip".

Suppose foldertozip is under "Documents"

So something like this should work:

```
shutil.make_archive("~/Documents/zipfile", "zip", "~/Documents/", "foldertozip")
```

Let us know if this works as expected for you!

Comment: Although my example was not what I really needed (it was just a simplification) the concept works...I didn't understand what the mentioned args were. BTW change *'"zip"* to *"zip"*